# What came first: the work-energy theorem OR work and energy individually which were later reconciled in a theorem?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, work, history

What came first: the work-energy theorem OR work and energy individually, which were later related to each other by a theorem? 
**Were work and kinetic energy defined after arriving at the work-energy theorem?**
It seems like the latter is true, given arbitrarily coming up with expressions for energy and work ( and defining them individually ) and then discovering a relation just seems very difficult.

This is more of a history question than a physics one. I am clear about what work, energy, and the work-energy theorem are. I just want to know if Newton ( or whoever came up with this) thought about defining the dot product of force and displacement, called it work, and separately came up with the concepts of energy before knowing about the work-energy theorem.

Answer (score 3):

> What came first: the work-energy theorem OR work and energy
>   individually which were later reconciled in a theorem?

The work-energy theorem states that the net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy. It can be derived from Newton's second law. See the following for a derivation: https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-physics/chapter/work-energy-theorem/

However, work and energy individually are not necessarily reconciled to form the work-energy theorem.

For example, you can do work on an object without changing its kinetic energy. If you push a box with a constant force $F$ on a floor with friction at at constant velocity a distance $d$, you will do positive work $W=Fd$ on the box. But since the velocity is constant there will be no change in the kinetic energy of the box. That's because the kinetic friction force does an equal amount of negative work on the box taking the energy you gave the box and dissipating it as heat.

You can change the gravitational potential energy of an object without doing net work on the object. If you raise an object of mass $m$ starting from rest on the ground and bring it to rest at a height $h$ above the ground, the gravitational potential energy acquired by the earth-object system is $mgh$ and there is no change in its kinetic energy. That's because gravity does negative work on the object equal to the positive work you did on the object taking the energy you gave the object and storing it as gravitational potential energy of the earth-object system.

On the other hand, if an object undergoes a change in kinetic energy you can say that net work has been done on an object per the work-energy theorem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As a history of physics thing, conservation of energy was not included in the Principia, and was not part of Newton's original work at all.  There was an active debate in the 17th century about whether the "right" conserved quantity was proportional to $v$ or $v^2$ that wasn't resolved until Lagrange and Hamilton came along and established that the answer was "both"

Comment: @JerrySchirmer Thanks Jerry for the interesting historical background. Wasn't aware of the $v$ vs $v^2$ history.